# Width de uma <td> não fica do tamanho passado

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida aqui na montagem de formulário usando   e variados.

eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Nome:</td>
  <td>Senha:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Código</td>
  <td>E-mail</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="campo-grande">Número de RAPSI:</td>
</tr>
```

e o CSS:

```
table{
 margin:0;
padding:0;
}
tr{
 display:block;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin-top:5px;
 }
td{
 display:inline-block;
border:1px solid black;
 width:200px;
}  
.campo-grande{
 width:400px;
}
```

O que acontece é que o campo "Número de RAPSI" não fica com 400px de width, alguém sabe o que é? Não tenho muita experiencia com tabelas, caso ajude segue o codepen

http://codepen.io/haykou/pen/GtcxL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não entendi por que usar uma tabela, tirando os padrões de tabela via CSS... Se quiser mesmo usar tabela (se for para mostrar dados tabulares, ok, senão não recomendo), use `colspan="2"` na última célula, e remova as regras de `display` para `tr` e `td`:

```css
*{
  border-box:box-sizing;
}
table{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
tr{
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:5px;
}
td{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  padding:0;
}
.campo-grande{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Nome:</td>
      <td>Senha:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Código</td>
      <td>E-mail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="campo-grande">Número de RAPSI:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: @bfavaretto, sem querer desviar o escopo da questão, dava pra dizer porquê não funcionou do jeito que haykou fez?

Comment: Porque `display: inline-block` sofre interferência de *whitespace*, como as quebras de linha e indentação do HTML. @Cold

Comment: Ok, só pergunteo porque estive aqui tentando (mesmo sem `display: inline-block`) e não dava. Devo ter falhado em algo... Obrigado @bfavaretto

Comment: @Cold Olha como fica sem os espaços em branco: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LiGwJ A diferença do tamanho da última linha é por causa dos 2px de borda a mais nas linhas de cima (porque têm 2 células cada).

Comment: Esclarecidíssimo... vlw